# why using column title name is fine but not working with column index

Tags: python, pandas

if I use the below line to check if a column is all 0s, with column index 11

```
if ((df.columns[11] == 0).all() == True):
```

I got error saying:

```
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'all'
```

however if I use the column title 'V2' instead, it works fine

```
if ((df['V2'] == 0).all() == True):
```

not sure what is the catch here?

Comment: df.columns returns list of column names not series, .all() method is applicable for series, and df['V2'] is a series and condition on it will also return the boolean series,

Comment: how should I do it if I need to use the index number instead of the name?

Comment: Use iloc for that

Comment: or if you use slices you can use it like this: `df[df.columns[11]]` its much simpler to just: `df.iloc[:, 11]` though

Comment: I am using 'if ((df.iloc[:, 11:17] == 0).all() == True):'   it has error 'The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().'

Comment: `(df.iloc[:,11] == 0).all()` i guess

Comment: i am selecting column 11 to 17 tho